# html5 video background safari and Windows Phonenot found

Tags: html, video, safari, html5-video

i want a video background in my new landing page, the video background  is fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE, but not in Safary and Windows Phone.
This is my code:

```
<video autoplay loop  id="video-background" muted>
    <source src="video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Does Safari needed other video format?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Does the `<video>` element display on the page?  If so, does adding the `controls` attribute cause it to start working?  I just tried on my WP8 device and the `autoplay` attribute didn't seem to work for me, but after adding the `controls` attribute I could click the play button that appears and the video worked correctly.  If this turns out to be the case, try leaving out the `autoplay` attribute and start the video with javascript instead.